# Block Domain User login

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller, active-directory

I have created a Domain User id ( for example - Auser ). I have integrated my LDAP login with Firewall. I use this user to login in to firewall only. So, I want to block all the login for this User except on Firewall.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

As per my knowledge, we can specify :-

1. By right click on **Domain User --> Properties --> Account tab --> Logonto** ( but here we have to specify Computer Name, we don't have any computer name for Firewall -- So i can't use this option )
2. Through **Group Policy Window Setting --> Security Setting --> Local Policies --> User Rights Assignment --> Allow logon Locally** (But it has to apply on Computer OU -- So i can't use this option also )

Any Other Option you know ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN ADUC --> Domain User --> Properties --> Account tab --> Logonto Enter your DC name ( both Primary and Secondary ), and than Check.

By Default, User can't login to your DC, so u don't need to worry and your problem will be solved.
I has also solved by this way.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall is likely just doing an LDAP lookup, not an interactive logon, so setting the "logon to" field of that account to nothing should still let you log into the firewall.

Comment: First of all we can't set Nothing on "Logon to" field, so i try to keep as "." in Logonto field, after that it has started to generate Error logs on my DC, So i removed it. Anyway, Thanks for ur Reply.